# Telegram steam hyperlink not working with steam:// links

Tags: hyperlink, telegram, steam

Can't create custom xdg-open hyperlink for opening in steam.
For example: 
 `<a href="steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198023163691A3283631559D17213532160030693475">VIEW</a>`

I set `parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML` in sendMessage args (Python). It's working with usual links, but not with `steam://` links.